# Download speed and ping suffers during PC to PC file copy

Tags: networking, download, network-adapter, lag, latency

**Why does the ping and internet download speed suffer on PC#1 when files copied from PC#1 to PC#2?**

During file copy, my ping goes from 20ms to 600ms+, Download speed goes from 1.8MB/S to 250 KB/S give or take.

I am downloading files On PC#1_Drive#C and PC#2 is copying files from PC#1_Drive#D. So it is not the hard drive perhaps.

My network looks like this and in a house where a main line goes to a room and if there are multiple devices I have installed a switch. While far from perfect the network has "evolved". I hope I have represented the basic network well enough.

```
DSL Router <-> 1Gb Switch#1 <-> PC#1 (1Gb Network card) "The Office"

1Gb Switch#1 <-> 1Gb Switch#Central <-> 1Gb Switch#2 "The Central Room"

1Gb Switch#2 -> PC#2 (100Mb Network Card) "The Lounge"

(All cable is Cat6)
```

Why is there a speed difference? How can I determine the problem?

AFAIK, the switches do not need to be in any particular port.
When PC#2 is copying files using a network path past PC#1 (if you can call it that way), to PC#3. PC#1 does not have a speed issue.

Comment: At the speeds mentioned for everything, there shouldn't be a bottleneck causing this problem anywhere. Would need to do some testing (laptop you can move around and plug into different parts of the network) to test further cases to see if one of the switches is the problem, or perhaps one of the original PCs (either 1 or 2)

Answer (score 0):

Let's use an analogy. The network is like a railroad. Trains can only go in one direction at a time (since there is only one track) and only a limited amount of cars (data packets) can be moved by each engine.

Copying a file from PC1 to PC2 involves moving the data and returning an ACK signal to indicate that there were no errors in the transfer.

When you download a file from the internet to PC1, you again have 2 way communication.

The one problem is the collisions that happen when PC1 sends a data package when a package arrives from the internet. Since the information is stacked on top of each other, the receiving computers ignore the data (since it is not understood). After a time, since an ACK signal was not received, the data is resent. Your data speed drops because of the traffic on the network.